# Building a dynamic HTML list from MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a set of tables (for this question I'll say two) in the database, one of which is the users table and one of which is one for storing URL's. The one that store URL's contains the URL ID (auto increment) and the User_ID. The user id is submitted when the add url form is submitted.

I'm trying to figure out how I can display these results as a table. For each user I need to get the list of URL's that are associated with their account and display them as a list. I have the user-id stored as a variable so it can be called from anywhere. How would I select items from the database that are only associated with the current logged in users id? and also how would I then generate a list of the results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic php mysql question so you can probably find it by looking around the site but to save you some time:

```
    //assuming the userid for logged in user is in $userid
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM urls_table WHERE User_ID=$userid";
    $result = mysql_query($sql); $data = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row['URL'];
    }
    print_r($data);
    //or foreach($data as $url) print "$url\n";
```

If instead of the user id of the logged in user you had the name then do an inner join like so:

```
    //assuming the user name for logged in user is in $username
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM urls_table INNER JOIN users_table ON urls_table.User_ID = users_table.User_ID WHERE User_Name=$username";
    $result = mysql_query($sql); $data = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row['URL'];
    }
    print_r($data);
    //or foreach($data as $url) print "$url\n";
```